# ¿Por qué no decimos "crocodilo"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, sustantivos

En [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocodylidae) se encuentra el nombre de la familia (imagino que será latín) a la que pertenecen los cocodrilos:

> Los crocodílidos (Crocodylidae) son una familia de saurópsidos (reptiles) arcosaurios comúnmente conocidos como cocodrilo

También está el nombre científico de uno en particular:

> Una especie, el cocodrilo marino (*Crocodylus porosus*) es el mayor de los cocodrilos de la actualidad

Hasta acá uno pensaría que lo correcto es crocodilo...

Mirando en otros idiomas:

- Inglés: crocodile
- Alemán: Krokodil

Igual esas son lenguas germanas, pero yendo un poco más cerca a nuestra lengua:

- Portugués: crocodilo
- Francés: crocodile

¿Por qué en español se dice cocodrilo?

Comment: Probablemente se deba a la dificultad con la que se pronuncia en un dictado fluido.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

¿Sabíais que en el DLE, de hecho, está registrada la palabra ***[crocodilo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BKlR2nm)***? Dice que es voz poco usada, pero parece que algo se usa a fin de cuentas.

En todo caso, ambas formas (*crocodilo* y *cocodrilo*) aparecen en el diccionario de Covarrubias de 1611. Ya por entonces la versión *cocodrilo* debía ser la más usada, dado que la entrada de *crocodilo* redirige a aquella. Eso sí, en la entrada de *cocodrilo* bien se asegura nada más empezar de decir que

> està corrõpido el vocablo de Crocodilo [...].

Para luego pasar a usar "crocodilo" en el resto de la definición. De hecho, en el *Diccionario de autoridades* (1729) pasa al revés: "cocodrilo" simplemente redirige a "crocodilo". Esto hace notar que, al menos hasta principios del siglo XVIII, la versión "crocodilo" era considerada la culta, y "cocodrilo" vendría a ser algo así como decir "cocreta" (solo que aceptado). Sin embargo, esto no tardó en revertirse, porque en 1780 ya la definición de "crocodilo" redirigía a "cocodrilo".

La explicación es, como dice Paco, una metátesis producida por la mayor facilidad de pronunciación de una variante con respecto de la otra. La diferencia con "cocreta" es que la metátesis se produjo desde el primer momento, de hecho se encuentran casos de "cocodrilo" en textos del siglo XV, pero "crocodilo" no aparece hasta el siglo XVI (negritas mías):

> *La mandibula somerana non se mueue en njngunt anjmal afueras enel **cocodrilo**.*
>
> Anónimo, "Arte complida de cirugía", a 1450 (España).
>
> ---
>
> ...e fázense en aquel río unos grandes animales de cuatro pies que dizen **crocodilos**...
>
> Rodrigo Fernández de Santaella, "Traducción del Libro de Marco Polo", 1503 (España).

Hasta 1600 podemos encontrar en el CORDE 83 casos (en 36 documentos) de "cocodrilo", y 74 casos (en 16 documentos) de "crocodilo". Desde 1600 hasta 1699 hay 113 casos (en 68 documentos) de "cocodrilo" y 19 casos (en 6 documentos) de "crocodilo". Se nota ya una considerable disminución de "crocodilo" en favor de "cocodrilo".

En el caso de "cocreta", la metátesis no ha pasado de la expresión oral a la escrita, al haberse producido con posterioridad a la introducción de la palabra.

P.D.: Encuentro [la siguiente afirmación](https://dicciomed.eusal.es/lexema/cocodrilo) sobre la etimología de la palabra:

> Chantraine da por buena la etimología de Heródoto que lo explica por *krókē* κρόκη 'guijarro' y *drîlos* δρῖλος 'gusano', es decir 'lagarto que anda entre los guijarros' que se aplicó primero a las lagartijas, lagartos y finalmente a los cocodrilos.

P.D.2: Gracias a los [comentaristas en menéame](https://www.meneame.net/m/Etimologia/no-decimos-crocodilo) por aportar palabras con casos similares de metátesis:

- *[Salchicha](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X21qv8W)* cuando debería ser *salsicha*. En este caso parece que la metátesis ocurrió en italiano, de donde la importamos ya así.
- *[Costra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B7UhSrK)* cuando debería ser *crosta* (viene del latín *crusta*).
- *[Murciélago](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Q6me6bm)* cuando debería ser *murciégalo* (del latín *mur caecŭlus*).

Comment: Casi parece que estés diciendo que la gente que no sabe decir murcielago y dice murciegalo en su lugar es mas culta por ello :P

Comment: Pues un resumen de esta respuesta entraría por la puerta grande de Linguistics, en concreto en [How did 'cocodrilo' originate from 'crocodile'?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/3244/10160).

Answer (score 10):

Es un caso de metátesis parcial (movimiento de un sonido a otra parte de la palabra).

Normalmente estos fenómenos se consideran vulgares y no prosperan (p. ej. "cocreta"), pero algunas veces son las formas con metátesis las que prosperan (como "cocodrilo", "murciélago", etc.). No hay ninguna razón aparente para que unas veces sí y otras no.