# Usos y desusos - Deste ¿Cuando una palabra cae en desuso se considera un vulgarismo?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, historia

Mucho he escuchado que algunas palabras son vulgarismos y lo mismo pensaba de [*deste*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DSn3h29) (*de este*), hasta que me topé con Cervantes y *El Mio Cid* para darme cuenta que era bastante usada hace tiempo. Pero más que solo ser usada es que era utilizada para dar un significado solemne.

¿Entonces el uso de *deste* por su desuso caería en un vulgarismo o es ignorancia de los parlantes?

Algunos otros ejemplos podrían ser [*murciégalo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Q6me6bm) y [*almóndiga*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=20CAqSi).

Comment: Deste en verdad es más bien una convención ortográfica. La mayoría de los hablantes, al pronunciar «de este» van a decir algo más parecido a /'deste/ que /de'este/, aunque aún es perceptible la distinción, cosa que se ha perdido por completo en *del* (por tratarse de dos palabras átonas)

Comment: exacto, muy similar a empaz(en paz) que me gustaría que se agregara al diccionario.

Comment: Léase [¿Por qué no decimos “crocodilo”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22596/1674) sobre la metátesis.

Answer (score 2):

"¿Cuando una palabra cae en desuso se considera un vulgarismo?" de hecho es lo contrario:

> **[vulgarismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c5QpjUZ)**
> De *vulgar*<sup>1</sup> e *-ismo.*
>
> 1. m. Dicho o frase especialmente usada por el vulgo.

i.e. cuando alguien llama a una palabra o un frase un "vulgarismo", quiere decir que es una palabra/frase común, que se usa la gente normal. No (necesariamente) que lleva una connotación mala.

---

<sup>[*Vulgar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c5Ns9tE) tiene dos definiciones principales - en el hable normal, puede significar:</sup>

> <sup>*Que es impropio de personas cultas o educadas.*</sup>

<sup>pero clásicamente, y en el campo de lingüística, significa:</sup>

> <sup>*Perteneciente o relativo al vulgo.*</sup>
>
> <sup>*Dicho de una lengua: Que se habla actualmente, por contraposición a las lenguas sabias.*</sup>

<sup>Es fácil ver como de una definición la otra ha emergido.</sup>