# Is "Probecita/o" a "sloppy" way of saying "Pobrecita/a"?

Tags: coloquialismos

*The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn* has this line:

> Po' little 'Lizabeth! po' little Johnny!

The Spanish translation of that is:

> *¡Probecita Lizabeth! ¡Probecito John!*

Since the speaker says "po'" instead of "poor", is that why the translator transmogrifies "pob**r**ecit" into "p**r**obecit", or is it a double typo?

That can hardly be, because a little later it reads:

> *¡Ay, probecita! ¡Que el Señor y todos los santos perdonen al pobre Jim!*

...and later yet:

> Poor things! to be left alone in the cold world so.
>   *¡Pobrecitas! Quedarse así solas en este frío mundo...*

Is it common for less-educated (or younger) ones to pronounce "pobrecita/a" as "probecita/o"? It *is* easier to say...

Comment: Do you know where the translation was done? *probe* is common in Galician and  standard in Asturian (having undergone a process of metathesis to shift the R), and those are typically more rural areas than elsewhere in Spain. If it's a Spain translation, that would make sense (although I've not personally heard in Castilian).  No idea if *probe* is heard in Latin America, though.

Comment: Great, now I'm going to have [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIhY3PCyLNM) stuck in my head all day long. :-)

Comment: @Charlie I didn't see your comment before posting XD

Comment: It does not happen in (the parts I know of) Latin America, it likely is a translation done in Spain.

Comment: @VinkoVrsalovic But the relevant part is that it's not a typo. It just one way of translating the effect that is already present in the English original version. What term would you use?

Comment: Visit Argentina sometime, and you'll hear people say "pibicito/a".

Comment: Anyway it is just a local misuse, I've heard people of low education say that in Barcelona, but never from low education people in Chile, Perú or Ecuador. I mean **probe**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Probe** solo aparece en el DLE en 1803 y de 1817, con la definición:

> Lo mismo que POBRE

Por otro lado en el CORDE **probe** aparece en numerosas ocasiones, desde por ejemplo:

> ... este Núñez ... es un **probe** hombre é no tiene que prestar ...
>   [Anónimo, **1548**, *Testimonio original de información para el cargo y descargo de Pedro de Valdivia*]

hasta

> ... que ruegue a Dios le permita
>   vorvé a naser; pero **probe**.
>   [Anónimo, **1966**, *Canciones españolas*]

Comment: Still _probe_ is used in Asturian, a Spanish dialect spoken in north part of Spain.

Comment: @Ra_ Note that Asturian is, alongisde Mirandese, a language in the Leonese branch, not just a dialect (unless you're referring to the Castilian dialect spoken in Asturias, which in my experience only uses *pobre*)

Answer (score 12):

> Is it common for less-educated (or younger) ones to pronounce
>   "pobrecita/a" as "probecita/o"?

Yes, it is. In the late nineties there was even a summer hit called "Miguel Canales (**Probe** Miguel)" by Triana Pura.

> Ay que le estará pasando al "**probe**" Miguel
>  Que hace mucho tiempo que
>   no sale
>  Que le estará pasando al "**probe**" Miguel
>  Que hace mucho tiempo
>   que no sale

English translation

> What's happening to po' Miguel?
>  It's been quite a while since he came
>   out last time
>  What's happening to po' Miguel?
>  It's been quite a while since he
>   came out last time

You can watch it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8OJX_IaE44

Comment: In fact in Spanish you can get lots of examples of letter swapping, some of which become the norm: latin _crusta_ gave the spanish _costra_, the latin _parabola_ gave the spanish _palabra_, _miraculum_ gave _milagro_, _crocodilus_ gave _cocodrilo_ etc.

Comment: @enxaneta You're right but at some point of time those spurious words became the norm. That's not the case with "probe" yet.

Comment: Have you read the answer of @RosieMBanks?

Comment: @enxaneta Yes, of course. I've upvoted it.

Answer (score 8):

In the thread [Cambio de letras Probe/Pobre; Tadre/Tarde](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/cambio-de-letras-probe-pobre-tadre-tarde.348375/) you can see that people agree that this is definitely a vulgarism, and that is somewhat common

> *probe* en lugar de pobre o *Grabiel* por Gabriel es algo que se escucha con relativa frecuencia en Andalucía

The book [Modismos comparativos de Andalucía](https://books.google.com/books?id=I-QpcJ302yIC&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=probe%20por%20pobre&source=bl&ots=jbrZfliJmJ&sig=ACfU3U0t9j0iZBS8L-x0HYgGqE3hLt-2ow&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmxp2osJjgAhVsplkKHTDQCqYQ6AEwDXoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=probe%20por%20pobre&f=false) indicates that this is a case of *metathesis* (in grammar, the transposition of sounds or letters in a word), although the book adds no further details about how pervasive this particular example would be.

The (google)book [Noticia sobre un libro que ha publicado el Sr. D. Francisco Silvela](https://books.google.com/books?id=ad0CAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=probe%20por%20pobre&source=bl&ots=E28KhNQRs9&sig=ACfU3U2b8wOipDp_ham4tnfsX2aXmfWMfw&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmxp2osJjgAhVsplkKHTDQCqYQ6AEwDnoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=probe%20por%20pobre&f=false) indicates that *probe* is in fact a vulgarism, corruption of "pobre", but highlights the interesting note that [pobre](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TSXVHEa) comes from latin *pauper*, and that you have *probe* in some other languages like Galician and Portuguese. The book claims that due to this it might be easier to hear *probe* instead of *pobre* in the west of Spain (in communities that are closer to Portugal or Galicia).

As an answer to an existing question explains in [¿Por qué no decimos “crocodilo”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22599/5481), sometimes these examples of *metathesis* are the ones that prosper, instead of the regular form. Nevertheless, *probe* is a vulgarism that seems in fact to be the perfect fit for the original "**Po'** little 'Lizabeth!"